# GDB error on running a C++ Program

Tags: c++, c++11, gdb

The list of files in my directory (which is /home/ayush/Desktop/xapian-patch/xapian/xapian-letor/bin) is

```
xapian-prepare-trainingfile.1  xapian-prepare-trainingfile.cc xapian-prepare-trainingfile  xapian-prepare-trainingfile.o
```

I am able to run the command `./xapian-prepare-trainingfile --db=/home/ayush/Documents/data/db /home/ayush/Documents/data/query.txt /home/ayush/Documents/data/qrel.txt /home/ayush/Documents/data/sample3.txt`

However When I try to run the same command through GDB

```
gdb --args xapian-prepare-trainingfile --db=/home/ayush/Documents/data/db /home/ayush/Documents/data/query.txt /home/ayush/Documents/data/qrel.txt /home/ayush/Documents/data/sample3.txt
```

i get the error

```
"/home/ayush/Desktop/xapian-patch/xapian/xapian-letor/bin/xapian-prepare-trainingfile": not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

I want to know how the run the c++ command that I am able to run without any problems through GDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `"/home/ayush/Desktop/xapian-patch/xapian/xapian-letor/bin/xapian-prepare-trainingfile": not in executable format: File format not recognized`

The most likely reason for above error is that `./xapian-prepare-trainingfile` is a shell script, not an executable file.

You can confirm this by running `file xapian-prepare-trainingfile`.

If it is a shell script, you'll need to run:

```
bash -x ./xapian-prepare-trainingfile ...
```

and figure out what actual executable it eventually invokes, and debug *that*.

Another way: make a copy of `xapian-prepare-trainingfile`, edit it, and insert `gdb --args` *just before* the script `exec`s the actual binary.